# Is "alpha-" and "-bet", in the word "alphabet", related to the first two letters "A" (alpha) and "B" (beta)?

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology, alphabets

I was reading the book *The Information: A History, A Theory, A Flood* by *James Gleick*.

Towards the beginning (third paragraph) of chapter three, titled *Two Wordbooks*, the author writes -

> The alphabet, however, had a definite order—the first and second
> letters providing its very name and that order had been maintained
> since the early Phoenician times, through all the borrowing and
> evolution that followed.

The context just before introducing this sentence does not make the meaning clear right away. I am guessing what the author wants to say is that the very word "alphabet" is a derivative of the first two letters of the alphabet system - "alpha" and "beta" respectively.

Am I correct in guessing the intent and the actuality of this claim? Or does the author indicate towards something else?

Comment: Yes; the original Semitic letters were "ox" Aleph, and 'house' Bet. Aleph became Alpha in Greek, Bet became Beta. This is also the source of the pattern in the words _Abjad_, which is a form of writing showing only  consonants, like Hebrew without vowel points; and also _Abugida_, a form of writing with intrinsic vowels for every consonant, like Sanskrit or Hindi.

Comment: Here on the linguistics SE one is not supposed to ask questions one hasn’t already tried to answer for oneself. Did you check any dictionaries? As one example, [Merriam-Webster gives the etymology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alphabet) of *alphabet* as “Middle English *alphabete*, from Late Latin *alphabetum*, from Greek *alphabētos*, from *alpha* + *bēta* beta.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you are right: the word "alphabet" comes from the first 2 letters of the Greek alphabet, *alpha* and *beta*. They got their alphabet from the Phoenicians, who had a different order and names for their letters. The Greeks added vowels and changed some of the shapes and sounds. So *alpha* is like the Phoenician *aleph* and *beta* is like the Phoenician *beth*.

Comment: Do you have evidence that the Phoenicians used a different order for their alphabet? I know that there were two different orders in use in that family of scripts in ancient times (the other order is still used for the fidal, the Amharic syllabary) but I've never heard that Phoenician used anything other than aleph-beth.

Comment: @ColinFine Maybe he's referring to the order of ע and פ.

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton ayin occurs before pe in Phoenician, just as omicron occurs before pi (the corresponding letters) in Greek

Comment: @ColinFine I guess you could potentially interpret the Greek sibilants in a way where Greek has the sibilants in a different order (but the other letters in place). The more usual explanation that the names fell out of alignment with the letter shapes and order seems simpler