# Are there clear exceptions to the alleged universality of "alphabet" as a term used in all languages

Tags: etymology, alphabets

In the book *The Information: A History, A Theory, A Flood* by James Gleick there is a bold claim:

> In all the languages of earth there is only one word for alphabet (alfabet, alfabeto, алфавит, αλφάβητο).

How (in)accurate is this statement? [As someone else has asked about here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47775/is-alpha-and-bet-in-the-word-alphabet-related-to-the-first-two-letters) in reference to the same book, the word from the comes from the combination of *alpha* and *beta*. From what I understand the Arabic الأبجدية is based on four letters instead of two, but that's close enough. The Icelandic [*stafróf*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stafr%C3%B3f) or various East Asian languages like the Chinese [字母](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E6%AF%8D) (*zìmǔ*) seem likely to be unrelated? Or do these words also have a direct relationship to "alphabet" as Gleick's statement would seem to imply?

Comment: One of the names of the Javanese script is [_Hanacaraka_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_script#Order) after the reading of the first five symbols, the whole set of which makes up a full meaningful sentence in the Javanese language.

Comment: There are alphabets and writing systems or scripts. Chinese and Japanese use characters, which constitute  writing systems.

Comment: This claim reads like a rather typical Westerner refusing to acknowledge the many thousands of languages they don’t have good (if any) knowledge of. I had thought of a dozen counterexamples off the top of my head before reading any of the answers (and then found all of them covered already, hence my not contributing an answer), though it’s worth noting that a number of cases arise because of their point of contact with the concept of writing, usually from Europe and almost invariably via a language that does use the term ‘alphabet’ (see for example isiZulu), though this is not always the case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is rather a bizarre claim to make in a widely published book, since it’s so easily disproven. There are **lots** of words for ‘alphabet’ that are different from the English term.

#### Alphabet, abjad, abugida et al.: based on first elements in the system

The word *alphabet* comes from Ancient Greek ἀλφάβητος *alfábētos*, which is based on ἄλφα *álfa* and βῆτα *bḗta*, the first two letters of the Greek alphabet. It’s perfectly true that this word has spread far and wide. The Romans borrowed it into Latin, and the Romance languages have inherited it (or re-borrowed it) from there; English borrowed it in Middle English, and the combined influence of Greek, Latin, English, French, Spanish and Portuguese (the latter as colonising languages) has meant that the word for ‘alphabet’ is now ultimately based on the Greek word in hundreds, if not thousands, of languages around the world.

It’s also true that similar naming principles, based on the first few elements in the system, apply in other scripts and many languages. From the Latin alphabet, we have forms like German *Abece* (and English *ABC*), Czech *abeceda*, Malagasy *abidy* (Malagasy doesn’t use *c*) – and then there’s a whole group based on Latin *abecedārium*: Catalan *abecedari*, Spanish *abecedario*, Irish *abítir*, Welsh *gwyddor* (yes, *abecedārium* becomes *gwyddor* in Welsh!), etc.

Examples from other writing systems include the following, plus of course the many words across many languages that are based on each of them:

| Language | Form | Origin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arabic | ألفباء *ʾalifbāʾ* | first two letters: *ʾalif* and *bāʾ*; ultimately the same names as *alpha* and *beta*, but seemingly independently formed in Arabic |
| Arabic | أبجد *ʾabjad* | first four letters: *ʾalif*, *bāʾ*, *jīm*, *dāl* |
| Georgian | ანბანი *anbani* | first two letters: *an*, *ban* |
| Ge’ez | አቡጊዳ *’äbugida* | same as *abjad*, just with the Ge’ez names of the letters |
| Armenian | այբուբեն *ayb‑u‑ben* | first two letters: *ayb* and *ben* (*u* = ‘and’) |
| Old Church Slavonic (now Pan-Slavic) | азъбоукꙑ *azŭbuky* | first two letters in the Glagolithic alphabet: *azŭ* and *buky* |
| Amharic | ሀሁ *hahu* | two of the [*fidäl*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fid%C3%A4l) in the first row: ሀ *ha* and ሁ *hu* |

(Aside: I’m sure I’ve seen a reference to the [traditional Amharic sorting order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%CA%BDez_script#List_order) ሀለሀመ *halähamä* being used as a word for the script itself, but I can’t find it now)

Those are not technically the same word, but they’re based on the same principle, so reading Gleick’s statement generously and broadly, with “one word” meaning ‘one way of forming the word’, so we can just about allow that.

#### Names based on other things

But there’s a whole host of words that we definitely cannot allow as being the same word, or even the same principle as all those. You’ve identified two of them yourself in the question, but there are many more. The most common principle is a simple explanatory word meaning something along the lines of ‘list of letters’, or indeed just reusing the word for ‘letter’ for the whole alphabet.

Here are a few examples, most of which I just got from the *Translations* section of the [Wiktionary article for *alphabet*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alphabet) (many are in languages I don’t speak, so I’m relying on the etymologies given in Wiktionary):

| Language | Form | Meaning | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Icelandic | *(bók)stafróf* | ‘row of letters’ | *stafur* = ‘staff, letter’; *-róf* = ‘row’, borrowed from Old English (cf. Old English [*stæfrōf*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/st%C3%A6frof#Old_English)) |
| Faroese | *(bók)stav(a)rað* | ‘row of letters’ | as Icelandic *(bók)stafróf* |
| Sanskrit | वर्णमाला *varṇamālā* | ‘series of shapes’ |  |
| Sanskrit | अक्षर *akṣara* | ‘letter’ | literally ‘unbreakable [unit]’, referring to a word, letter, sound, vowel, etc.; not a common word for the whole system in Sanskrit, but very common as a borrowing in later languages (sometimes with a suffix equivalent to Skt. माला *mālā* ‘row, string’) |
| Finnish | *aakkoset*, *aakkosto* | ‘(collection of) letters’ | from *aakko* ‘letter’ (itself from *aa* ‘the letter a’ + *-kko* [collective suffix]) + *-nen* (adjectival suffix) or *-sto* (collective suffix) |
| Estonian | *tähestik* | ‘series of letters’ | from *tähti* ‘star, letter’ + *-stik* (collective suffix) |
| Tamil | அகரவரிசை *akaravaricai* | ‘row/series of *akaram*’ | *akaram* = a name for the first vowel in the script, ‘a’ |
| Thai | ตัวอักษร *dtuua-àk-sɔ̌ɔn* | ‘letter-letter’ | apparently from *dtuua* ‘letter’ + *àk-sɔ̌ɔn* ‘letter’ (< Sanskrit *akṣara*) |
| Vietnamese | *bảng chữ cái* | ‘letter table’ | *bảng* = table, *cái* = base, *chữ* = character (< Chinese 字, see below) |
| Ge’ez | ፊደል *fidäl* | ‘letter(s)’ |  |
| Arabic | حروف *ḥurūf* | ‘letters’ | pl. of حرف *ḥarf* (borrowed into Malaysian and Indonesian, among others) |
| Circassian | тхыпкъылъэ *txəpqəlˢɛ*, хьэрыфылъэ *ḥɛrəfəlˢɛ* | ‘collection(?) of letters’ | from тхыпкъэ *txəpqɛ* / хьарыф *ḥarəf* ‘letter’ (the latter borrowed from Arabic) + something that I’m guessing is a collective suffix or similar |

And then there are sundry other formations:

| Language | Form | Meaning | Origin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Greenlandic | *oqaasiliuutissat* | ‘things that will be used to turn into words’(?) | I **think** it’s *oqaaseq* ‘word’ + *-lior* ‘make into’ + *-uti* ‘instrument, means’ + *-ssaq* ‘future’ + *-t* ‘plural’ |
| Korean, Japanese | 문자 *munja*, 文字 *moji* | ‘script characters’ | borrowed from Chinese where it’s broader and just means ‘language, writing, script, text’ |
| Breton, Cornish | *lizherenneg*, *lytherennek* | ‘letterese’ | from *lizher/lyther* ‘letter (missive)’ (borrowed from French/Latin) + *-enn* (singulative suffix) + *-eg/-ek* (suffix normally used for languages) |
| Chinese (Mandarin) | 字母 *zìmǔ* | ‘mother of a character’ | referring originally to the [initial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#Chinese_model) in a syllable in Chinese phonology, or to the character used to illustrate this initial in [*fǎnqiè*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanqie) |
| Udi | тӏетӏир *ṭeṭir* | ‘primer, ABC book, alphabet’ | borrowed from Armenian տետր *tetr* referring to a primer, from Greek τέτρας *tétras* ‘quaternion, quire (four-leaf book)’ |
| Mongolian | цагаан толгой *cagaan tolgoj* | ‘white head’ | “apparently a popular name for primer books, supposed to mean ‘clear (= simple, easy) initials’” — @Quassnoi (in comments) |

#### Miscellaneous unknown formations

Just for the sake of Wiktionary completeness, here are some that don’t look like they belong to the first two groups, but since they’re in languages I don’t know and don’t have adequate entries or etymologies on Wiktionary, I don’t know how they’re actually formed (if anyone knows more, please feel free to add details and move to other categories if appropriate):

- Yup’ik *igat*
- Winnebago *woowagax* (if that’s even a real word)
- Navajo *saad bee álʼíní* – *saad* is ‘word’, don’t know the rest
- Māori *tātai reta*
- Lao ໂຕຫນັງສື *tō nang sư̄* and ແມ່ກໍກາ *mǣ kǭ kā*

Comment: (I’ve copy-pasted from Wiktionary in cases where I don’t actually know/read the language in question or script – please feel free to correct any errors I or Wiktionary may have introduced.)

Comment: Nice work, thanks!

Comment: You forgot Hebrew "Alef Bet"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "white heads", apparently, was a popular name for primer books, supposed to mean "clear (= simple, easy) initials"

Comment: @Quassnoi Ah, that would make sense!

Comment: _хьэрыфылъэ_ obviously from Arabic _harf_ "letter"

Comment: @Quassnoi So it seems: хьарыф _ḥarəf_ means ‘letter’ (no idea if the variation between ⟨а⟩ and ⟨э⟩ is accurate, regular, random…). Similarly, тхыпкъэ _txəpqε_ also means ‘letter’ (no etymology given). Presumably _-(ə)lˢɛ_ is then a collective suffix or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Plenty of languages have other words for it. Most Slavic languages, for example, use a word along the lines of *azbuky*, named after the first two letters of the Glagolitic alphabet instead of the Greek one. Other languages use a word originally meaning "letter", like Amharic *fidäl*.

Comment: I'd be willing to give the Slavic example to Gleick (that's still the first two letters of a presumably Greek-influenced alphabet) but the Amharic case seems like a strong counter-example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There exists the word "[*das Abece*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abc)" (often written as *Abc*) as a Germanisation of alphabet in German, and it has some currency in elementary school teaching.

Comment: Similar to “now you know your ABC” in English as well. But that’s still an example of using the first elements in the system to name the system.

Answer (score -2):

As a minor pet peeve I will argue with Micael P. Barnes (“Runes, a handbook”):

> Although “alphabet” is sometimes used of a total set of runes, the synonyms “rune-row“ and *futhark* are more precise.

The fact of the matter is that *futhark* betrays the order of letters of the *abc*, *the ΑΩ*, and the difference has to date no thorough explanation.

In the narrows sense of *alpha* /a/, “alphabet” names scripts which have phonemic vowels like the Greek one, including futhark, distinct from abugidas, abjads, and cetera. More over, even more narrow, dedicated literature pays attention to the order and specific values of the letters, so as to distinguish *'-b-g* from *a-b-c* and more diverse cases, like a by communis opinio younger *h-l-ḥ-m* sequence of Ugaritic from Bet Shemesh, though common practice ignores this. E.g. Sanskrit *devanagari* with its deviant albeit logical order is still classified as abugida, that is *semi-syllabary* on a syllabary to alphabetic cline.

Which is to say in lexikographical terms, the word can have different inclusive and exclusive meanings. The inclusive meaning is a generalization from the most common meaning lacking contrast. This is largely irrelevant, since the bulk of speakers is ignorant of foreign scripts. This *egality* is made explicit in translations. (@Draconis' answer is throwing a wrench in my take on the question, so dun matter is all I can say).

The exclusive meaning on the other hand depends on context. E.g. *devanagari* may be parsed as a foreign word or a terminus technicus, either synonym or contrasting. Its relation to Greek, Aramaic or  Phoenician is essentially obscure. Cf. HSK 10/1 „Schrift und Schriftlichkeit“ (1994) p. 323 for the genralizing point of view (translation mine, I don't fully agree):

> It is very likely that selection of symbols was based on certain regionaly known symbols which served the basic purpose of lettering [„Buchstabenschrift“].

> ... The assumption of a perhaps non-acrophonic selection offers the only solution for the parallelism of the linear sign inventory of the oldest alphabets of Byblos and the Aegean scripts.

Indeed I feel tempted to translate „Buchstabenschrift“ as *alpabetic* + *writing*, inasmuch as the etymology of *book-stave* may be controversial.

---

Nevertheles, a clear distinction can be drawn at the very least in the case of undeciphered scripts, on a philosophical level, in those controversial cases where it is undecided if the marks decode language proper or something else.

Comment: this doesn't appear to actually address the question. Additionally is there actually any evidence of "futhark" being used to refer to the runic alphabets (rather than just it being the start of abecedaries) in the Elder or Younger Futhark periods?

Comment: It works under the assumption that the OP is opinionated, and so, incidently, are you. Of course it addresses the OP. a) some call the futhark an alphabet, so it is in scope. b) this is wrong, and here is why. You cannot disagree with the first point, because it is a common fact, and you cannot disagree with the second point without addressing it, since it's sourced and rounded off by my own interpretation, but you haven't. You could agree with it, indicating that it renders the first point irrelevant, but that appears bikeshedding to the max, because you fail to notice the bigger implication.

Comment: [cont.] Your questioning appears to be irrelevant, as we have scarcely any running text in Elder Futhark, but definite evidence of the futhark sequence. Younger Futhark and Futhorc are not immediately relevant to my interest. My point was simply that the James Gleick and BrianZ alike are likely in the group of people who would call it alphabet. You, @Tristan, are in no position to disagree with that, obviously.